# Typescript tsc --declaration

Tags: typescript, tslint

When I generate my definition file ".d.ts" with tsc --declaration or with the tsconfig.json declaration true, the generate files do not include

declare module "mymodule" {...
}

This is not a problem for "vscode" but "tslint" seems to have trouble and warn me with " Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'." for example the file "test.ts" :

```
type PromiseResolve<T> = (value?: T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined) => void;


export async function delay(timeout: number): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve: PromiseResolve<boolean>): void => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(true); }, timeout);
    });
}
```

will generate

```
export declare function delay(timeout: number): Promise<boolean>;
```

but I need:

```
declare module "mymodule"
{
export declare function delay(timeout: number): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

How can I get the 'declare module "mymodule"{……}' in the top of my generated .d.ts ? Or how to make tslint work without this declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `--module system` and `--out` to get the output you are looking for:

Given that your file is in the file "mymodule.ts", the following command

```
tsc mymodule.ts --lib 'es6' --declaration -t es6 -module system -out mymodule.js
```

will generate:

```
declare module "mymodule" {
    export function delay(timeout: number): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This work! But i forget to specify : I use Nodejs so i need commonJS module and I have multiple files with differents function. So the mymodules.js contain multi => declare module "file1" {function of file 1}, declare module "file2" {function of file 2},... is there a way to do this with commonJs module and multiple file, but only one declare module declare module "mymodule" {function of file 1,function of file 2}?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your followup question, can you give the full example somehow?

Comment: more info given